# Error generating service worker when prerendering Angular Universal app

Tags: angular, npm

I get the follow error after running `npm run prerender`:

```
× Service worker generation failed.
host.exists is not a function
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! personal-website@0.0.0 prerender: `ng run personal-website:prerender && cpx proxy-server.js dist/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the personal-website@0.0.0 prerender script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\milanfc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-13T18_41_31_643Z-debug.log
```

If I run `ng build --prod`, the service worker is generated without a problem. What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try
npm i @angular/service-worker

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it didn't work. The service worker gets generated perfectly when when I run `ng build --prod`, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the prerender script?